# Como fazer a contagem de checkbox marcado ao clickar no submit?

Tags: php, javascript

Como implementar a contagem de checkbox marcados quando o usuário clickar em submit, quando ao menos dois campos foram marcados no código abaixo:

```
<script>
// Limita a quantidade de cliques
$(".limited1<?php echo $i; ?><?php echo $i4; ?>").click(function() {
    var bol = $(".limited1<?php echo $i; ?><?php echo $i4; ?>:checkbox:checked").length >= 1;     
    $(".limited1<?php echo $i; ?><?php echo $i4; ?>:checkbox").not(":checked").attr("disabled",bol);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para checar quantos checkboxes foram marcados na página você pode usar a seguinte função em javascript:

```
var array_checked = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
var number_of_checked = array_checked.length
```